# Error when South in INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: django, django-south

This is my 4th project using South, but the first time on Django 1.6 and there is something strange going on.

I'm able to run migrations fine, and the database is being updated. However, I'm getting unhandled exceptions when South is in the INSTALLED_APPS of my settings.py.

In the error log I'm seeing:

```
2013-12-09 15:42:18,123 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 339, in urlconf_module
2013-12-09 15:42:18,124 :    return self._urlconf_module
2013-12-09 15:42:18,124 :AttributeError: 'RegexURLResolver' object has no attribute '_urlconf_module'
```

Then there are 2 errors that Django returns "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:"
ImportError: No module named 'south'
ImportError: importlib._bootstrap is not a frozen module

1. When i remove South from the INSTALLED_APPS setting, I don't get the error.
2. I've read somethings about putting South in the last line of the INSTALLED_APPS, but that doesn't change anything for me.
3. I am able to import South in my Bash console
4. This is on a shared server and South is installed correctly and working correctly in different projects (but those projects are django 1.3, not 1.6)

Any ideas of why I'm getting the error when south is in my INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: What's your south version? Make sure using the latest version.

Comment: Thanks, forgot to mention the South verion is 0.8.1 which is compatible with Django 1.6 --> http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: It's also possible south is only installed for python2 if you run migrate with python2 it works. But django is launched with python3.

Comment: yup, that seems to be the problem. The bash console is launched with 2.7 apparently. I was able to launch a 3.3 console and I get the import error. Time to work with the admins of my hosting site. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

south is only installed for python2 if you run migrate with python2 it works. But django is launched with python3.
(copied comment as answer, to make it acceptable ;))

Answer (score 0):

kelvan's comment above explains what was happening. Python 3.3 fails to import south, but with a 2.7 console it imports correctly.